# How can i create a facebook account using java

Tags: java, facebook, api, account, createuserwizard

As a part of one enterprise application, I need to create a Facebook account for some users in an active directory. The enterprise application is running on java. How can i connect to the Facebook server for creating the users using java? Please point out the API's I have to use, if any are available.

**EDIT**: Is there any other social platform supports account creation using API?

Thanks and Regards,

Sunny.

Comment: I would guess that this would - at least in Facebook's opinion - violate the Facebook Terms of Service.  So if there existed such an API, it would not work very long after Facebook became aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there is not a method to create users via API.  They'll need to register manually and then you can use one of the SDK's to link the existing account into your app.

Answer (score 1):

FaceBook, Twitter, Gmail, ... have CAPTCHAs in the registration pages. So I believe you cannot do it programatically.